# BroadcastReceiver not called (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I have a class inherited from BroadcastReceiver()

```
class ConnectivityReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("Connection", "onReceive")
        if(ConnectionDetector(context!!).isConnectingToInternet) {
             Log.d("Connection", "Connected To Internet")
        }
        else {
             Log.d("Connection", "Not Connected To Internet")
        }
    }
}
```

And in MainActivity I am tryin to register it

```
private val receiver = ConnectivityReceiver()

private fun registerreciver() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.INTERNET),1)
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE),1)
    val filter = IntentFilter()
    filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
}
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(receiver)

}
```

But it's not called when I turn off/on Wi-Fi or mobile data. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a system broadcast. You register a receiver for it by calling `registerReceiver()` on a `Context`, not on the `LocalBroadcastManager` singleton.

Also note that:

- You do not need to request `INTERNET` as a runtime permission
- While `READ_PHONE_STATE` is a `dangerous` permission and one that you have to request at runtime, `requestPermissions()` is asynchronous, so you may not yet have that permission by the time `requestPermissions()` returns